# Data from a table getting printed to csv in a single line

Tags: python-3.x, csv, xpath, web-scraping

I've written a script to parse data from the first table of a website. I've used xpath to parse the table. Btw, I didn't use "tr" tag cause without using it I can still see the results in the console when printed. When I run my script, the data are getting scraped but being printed in a single line in a csv file. I can't find out the mistake I'm making. Any input on this will be highly appreciated. Here is what I've tried with:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

url="https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/"
response = requests.get(url).text
outfile=open('Data_tab.csv','w', newline='')
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Player","Team","Points","Cost"])
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for titles in tree.xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]:
    # tab_r = titles.xpath('.//tr/text()')
    tab_d = titles.xpath('.//td/text()')
    writer.writerow(tab_d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add a level of looping, examining each table row in turn.

Try this:

```
for titles in tree.xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]:
    for row in titles.xpath('./tr'):
        tab_d = row.xpath('./td/text()')
        writer.writerow(tab_d)
```

Or, perhaps this:

```
table = tree.xpath("//table[@class='ism-table']")[0]
for row in table.xpath('.//tr'):
    items = row.xpath('./td/text()')
    writer.writerow(items)
```

Or you could have the first XPath expression find the rows for you:

```
rows = tree.xpath("(.//table[@class='ism-table'])[1]//tr")
for row in rows:
    items = row.xpath('./td/text()')
    writer.writerow(items)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Robᵩ, for your robust solution. Both of the codes just rock.